# Getting a value meanwhile doing curl request (Php)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a value from the HTML document that changes by the website's authority each time the page is refreshed, the value i will need is to execute a forum post.

The problem is if i execute the curl and get the values, and then re-execute it with the data to post my request this time, the data will have changed and it'll not accept it.

what do i do?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to bypass CSRF.

Comment: @Mihai Nope, it's called __EVENTVALIDATION, i need to get the value to complete the post request.

Comment: EVENTVALIDATION is similar to csrf, but can be bypassed. check out this article on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148013/fake-eventvalidation-in-microsoft-ajax